# How to disable auto mounting of root partition during systemd init embedded Linux

Tags: linux, systemd

I am trying to reduce the boot time with embedded Linux based on yocto.

One of the things I observed is the systemd is mounting the root partition which is passed as an kernel argument. The root partition is mounted already by the kernel, so I want to gain some time on this. Debugging, I commented the /etc/fstab, but still it was coming.

I think it come through udev rules when it detects device. Looking into this now.

Does anyone knows how to disable the remount of root partition in systemd ?

Answer (score 0):

Many Linux boxes use an [initrd](https://systemd.io/INITRD_INTERFACE/) as an early user space to get / mounted. Which is not trivial in the general case, encryption, LVM, network file systems.  The switch-root operation is normal. See also systemd's [boot diagram](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html) of how these early targets work.  You could try getting a non-initrd system booting by ensuring the kernel doesn't need one (what storage do you have?) and commenting out the initrd in the bootloader, but that seems tricky.

Find what really is taking boot time with `systemd-analyze`. Without arguments it shows subtotals of early kernel, initrd, and user time. `systemd-analyze plot >bootup.svg`  generates a chart that more accurately what is started concurrently. This step is just collecting data to prove a hypothesis. Further analysis is needed of which units are actually on the critical chain, and how they might be made faster.